# SWIG php how to call reference arguments

Tags: arguments, swig

I am trying to use my C++ libraries in PHP with SWIG, everything work fine and I generated my shared object precisely. I also include phppointers.i and std_string.i in my interface file. but when I want to call my C++ methods which have reference or pointer arguments in their input section, the method just would not work properly or I got some errors like :

```
Fatal error:no matching function
```

for example one of my methods is declared as below:

```
int func(string &ptr,bool space=true) const;
```

but when I call this method in my php code as:

```
$bf->func('abcd',true);
```

I got this error:

```
Fatal error:no matching function
```

I tried to call this function with other ways like:

```
$str = 'abcd';
$bf->func(&$str,true);
```

but this time I got following error:

```
Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed
```

I am totally confused, I truly appreciate if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: If you're not modifying ptr in the method make it const and it will work. If you are modifying it calling like your example makes no sense. Const correctness is important.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, if I make it const it works fine, but I have no access to C++ source code, I mean I only have object file and header file and can not make any changes in source code, is there any solution that I can call func without making any changes in its declaration?? Actually when I read the swig manual, figured out that SWIG changes the reference calls to pointers in the wrapper class, with this approach the ptr is a pointer in my method, I wonder how to call this pointer inside the PHP code? thank you so much for all your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [swig no matching function for overloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331017/swig-no-matching-function-for-overloaded) - these two questions seem to both be the same issue.