# Swig: How to typemap c++ string const & to python string?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a constructor with these prototypes:

```
YCPTerm(const string& s);
YCPTerm(const string& s, const YCPList& l);
YCPTerm(bytecodeistream & str);
```

I'm using swig to generate python bindings. In python, I try to call the constructor, and get this:

```
>>> import ycp
>>> ycp.YCPTerm("Empty")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ycp.py", line 575, in __init__
    this = _ycp.new_YCPTerm(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_YCPTerm'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    YCPTerm::YCPTerm(string const &)
    YCPTerm::YCPTerm(string const &,YCPList const &)
    YCPTerm::YCPTerm(bytecodeistream &)
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427096/663279) which seems to be a similar issue, but a typemap typecheck didn't work for me.

This is what I tried:

```
%typemap(typecheck,precedence=141) const std::string& str {
  $1 = Z_TYPE_PP($input) == IS_STRING;
}
```

How do I solve this? Do I need an in and out typemap to convert the value? I've been [reading about typemap's here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html), and am not sure how to typemap a const string&.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std_string.i` library includes the typedefs that do conversions back and forth between `std::string` and Python strings. See [the documentation on the std::string library in SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_std_string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer here](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Hopefully-an-easy-one-SWIGTYPE-p-string-td3334.html).

Adding these lines to my .i file fixed the error:

```
%include std_string.i
%inline %{
using namespace std;
%}
```

I don't understand the why though. Maybe someone else can answer that.